# $S_n$ notation in permutations

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

What does notation $S_n$ stands for? 

For example if I have the following set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ so we say that $S_4$=24?

Moreover in many examples I saw the use of following numbers like $\{1,2,...,n\}$ but permutation can work on too on a set like $\{3,5,7\}$?
If so, we say that $S_3=6$?

Comment: $S_n$ stands for the group of permutations of $n$ things.  The $S$ stands for *symmetric*, as this group is also called the symmetric group.

Comment: In particular we won't say that $S_4=24$, but that the group $S_4$ has 24 elements. In general $S_n$ has $n!$ elements.

Comment: From wikipedia: "Since there are n! (n factorial) possible permutation operations that can be performed on a tuple composed of n symbols, it follows that the order (the number of elements) of the symmetric group Sn is n!."

so we the $n$ in $S_n$ counts the number of elements in the set, so for $\{4,12,18\} $ it $S_3$?

Answer (score 1):

$S_n$ is the set of all bijections from $\{ 1, 2, \dots, n \}$ to itself. In particular, $S_n$ has $n!$ elements (which we call permutations). A cyclic permutation is usually denoted by $$(a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_j)$$ where $a_{i-1} \mapsto a_i$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, j-1$ and $a_j \mapsto a_1$.

Comment: That's only a way of denoting cyclic permutations. Not all permutations are cyclic.